# Predicting unknown faces in face recognition

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a convolutional neural network to recognize faces. The issue is that I want to train on 10 classes, and be able to predict more than 10 classes at test time (e.g. 20 classes).

How could I do that without affecting the test accuracy rate of the recognition of the older file ? Because I get a low test accuracy and sometimes 0.

---

Here is my code.

```py
batch_size = 16
patch_size = 5
depth = 16
num_hidden = 128
num_labels = 12
num_channels = 1 

def reformat(dataset, labels):
  dataset = dataset.reshape(
    (-1, IMAGE_SIZE_H, IMAGE_SIZE_W, num_channels)).astype(np.float32)


  labels = (np.arange(num_labels) == labels[:,None]).astype(np.float32)

def accuracy(predictions, labels):

  return (100.0 * np.sum(np.argmax(predictions, 1) == np.argmax(labels, 1))
          / predictions.shape[0])   


graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():

  # Input data.

  tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(
    tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, IMAGE_SIZE_H, IMAGE_SIZE_W, num_channels))
  print("tf_train_dataset",tf_train_dataset)
  tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
  tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
  tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

  layer1_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
      [patch_size, patch_size, num_channels, depth], stddev=0.1))
  layer1_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([depth]))

  layer2_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
      [patch_size, patch_size, depth, depth], stddev=0.1))
  layer2_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[depth]))

  layer3_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
      [IMAGE_SIZE_H // 16 * IMAGE_SIZE_W // 16 * depth, num_hidden], stddev=0.1))
  layer3_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[num_hidden]))

  layer4_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(
      [num_hidden, num_labels], stddev=0.1))

  layer4_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[num_labels]))

    conv_1 = tf.nn.conv2d(data, layer1_weights, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    hidden_1 = tf.nn.relu(conv_1 + layer1_biases)
    pool_1 = tf.nn.max_pool(hidden_1,ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides= [1,2,2,1],padding ='SAME' )
    conv_2 = tf.nn.conv2d(pool_1, layer2_weights, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    hidden_2 = tf.nn.relu(conv_2 + layer2_biases)
    pool_2 = tf.nn.max_pool(hidden_2,ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides= [1,2,2,1],padding ='SAME' )

    shape = pool_2.get_shape().as_list()
    reshape = tf.reshape(pool_2, [shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])
    hidden_3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, layer3_weights) + layer3_biases)
    return tf.matmul(hidden_3, layer4_weights) + layer4_biases

  # Training computation.

logits = model(tf_train_dataset)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits,tf_train_labels))


  # Optimizer.

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

  # Predictions for the training, validation, and test data.

train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_valid_dataset))
test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(model(tf_test_dataset))

num_steps = 201

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:

    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()  
    print('Initialized')
    for step in range(num_steps):
      offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size) 
      batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :, :, :]
      batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
      feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset : batch_data, tf_train_labels : batch_labels}
      _, l, predictions = session.run(
        [optimizer, loss, train_prediction ], feed_dict=feed_dict)
      if (step % 50 == 0):
        print('Minibatch loss at step %d: %f' % (step, l))
        print('Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%' % accuracy(predictions, batch_labels)
        print('Validation accuracy: %.1f%%' % accuracy(
          valid_prediction.eval(), valid_labels))
    print('Test accuracy: %.1f%%' % accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels[:,0:9]))
```

Comment: changing the testing data will not affect the trained network, and the accuracy on old testing data should be stable.

Comment: How can you predict classes which are not at all in train set ?

Comment: yes i know if i delete the images that aren't trained it gives me a high accuracy, but my project is to create new classes if is not available in the trained dataset

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to train a model with cross entropy on a certain number of classes (10 identities for you), and test it with different classes (e.g. the 10 training identities with 10 new ones, for a total of 20).

You would need anyway to get rid of the last softmax layer (of size `[num_hidden, 10]`) to use a new **untrained** softmax layer of size `[num_hidden, 20]`.

The issue is that this new layer will be randomly initialized and will yield very bad results.

---

The general solution to deal with unknown classes in deep learning is to construct a very good representation of each input data (the face) into a feature space (of size `num_hidden`). This technique is called [representation learning](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_learning).

Imagine you have an excellent feature space where your model sends faces. In theory, all the faces of an identity will be sent to the same location, in a clean cluster. You will then be able to run k-means to get the identity clusters or any algorithm on top of that **embedding**, with `k` being the number of test identities (`k=20`).

---

There are multiple ways to get a good embedding. You can get the last hidden layer before your softmax, or even the last hidden layer of an already trained model ([VGGFace](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/vgg_face/) has very good results and are freely available).

Another interesting idea also developed in the VGGFace paper is to use **triplet loss** to finetune the embedding.

Comment: thanks @Olivier Moindrot, may be you are right, i have seen the link [VGGFace] but the contents files in matlab and i am not familiar with it, can i use VGG-Face CNN descriptors by using tensorflow?